# system crontab: how to run scripts as root AND as user

Tags: cron

I have an overnight script that performs a given user's housekeeping, then shuts down. Shutdown needs root privileges, but the admin tasks need to run as the user whose files are being cleaned up. The cleanup takes an indefinable time to run, so both cleanup and shutdown have to be in the same script. My question is how can I cron a script with these two commands, the first of which needs to be run by an ordinary user (say Bob); and the next needs to be run as root (shutdown) only after the first has completed. I have experimented with system crontab (which can run the admin as Bob, but then can't shutdown); and as root crontab (which can shutdown, but not run the admin tasks as Bob). Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo` to execute a command as another user.

I tried the following on Debian.

Wrote a script that included the following.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $HOME
```

And executed the following command as **root**.

```
sudo -u nonrootuser ./script && some-admin-command
```

Which printed `/home/nonrootuser` and executed the `some-admin-command`

which shows that root was able to execute both as a normal user and as root. So keep your user housekeeping script in the `script`, replace the `nonrootuser` with Bob and `some-admin-command` with the shutdown command and run it as root.

Answer (score 0):

In file cronjob, you can executed the following command command as:

```
0 5 * * * sudo -u nonrootser -H bash script.sh && some-command-another
```

And you can write a file script.sh that included the following as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```